# Looking for cross platform Packet Capture Library

Tags: c++, networking, cross-platform, packet-capture

beside wincap , is there any recommended cross platform Packet Capture Library
to use with c/c++ ? 
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the "pcap" interface.
Unix like system implement this interface with libpcap and Winpcap on windows.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pcap

Answer (score 0):

Packet Capture Tools:
http://www.hunch.com/performance-troubleshooting-with-packet-captures/